# Example of homomorphism of finite groups that preserves order but is not isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find an example of a homomorphism between finite groups that preserves the order of each domain element but is not an isomorphism.

I realize that I need to look for a map that fails to be surjective-- but cannot come up with one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any inclusion works, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi No, that's true I think. I just blanked.

Comment: Well if it preserves th order it is injective. Therefore it is an isomorphism onto its image : for a counterexample pick an isomorphism and then expand the image to a bigger group (see the previous comment : a strict incusion works well)

Comment: Hence a restatement of the question is: find a homomorphism between finite groups that is injective and not surjective.

Comment: @YCor  yes, extremely simple answer in retrospect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f:\mathbb{Z}_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ by $f(x)=2x$